# How to set Jetty Socket timeout

Tags: timeout, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to configure Jetty Server for Socket(read)timeout. I have one rest API exposed on the server and it might take well over 1 minute to send over data over the wire. Where can I set this so that Client doesn't get read timeout and gets all data over the wire? Or is on http connector I added to my server?

Answer (score 0):

A read timeout on the client wouldn't be controlled by a server setting.

For server level controls, you should be looking at Idle Timeout on the `ServerConnector`.